# Detecting garbage in a Unit Test

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I wanted to detect whether or not my code generates garbage. So I created the following unit test.

```cs
[TestClass]
public class AllocationTest
{
    int[] generationCollections = new int[3];

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGarbageGeneration()
    {
        generationCollections[0] = GC.CollectionCount(0);
        generationCollections[1] = GC.CollectionCount(1);
        generationCollections[2] = GC.CollectionCount(2);

        // Test for garbage here

        for (int generation = 0; generation < generationCollections.Length; generation++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(GC.CollectionCount(generation), generationCollections[generation]);
        }
    }
}
```

I put the code in question where the "Test for garbage here" comment is and the results are unpredictable. My understanding is that this is due to the fact that GC runs on a separate thread and can be triggered by code other than my test at any time.

I tried GC.Collect to forcefully run collections before and after the test code but then realized that that always increment the collection count, so that test always fails.

Is there a meaningful way to test for garbage in a unit test?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to profile memory usage of unit tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930172/is-it-possible-to-profile-memory-usage-of-unit-tests)

Comment: "that always increment the collection count", yes, but just by +1 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WMemoryProfiler](http://wmemoryprofiler.codeplex.com/) to find out how many additional types were created. If you profile your own process you will get all addtional created types + some instances used by WMemoryProfiler to generate the report.

You can work around by using a separate process to monitor your managaed heap or by limiting yourself to only your types. If you leak memory you will see it normally in addtional instances created by you.

```
  using (var dumper = new InProcessMemoryDumper(false,false))
  { 
     var statOld = dumper.GetMemoryStatistics();

     // allocaton code here
     var diff = dumper.GetMemoryStatisticsDiff(statOld);

    foreach (var diffinst in diff.Where(d => d.InstanceCountDiff > 1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Added {0} {1}", diffinst.TypeName, diffinst.InstanceCountDiff);
    }
  }
```

If you are after how much memory temporary objects did use you you will need to use some profiling Api or tools like PerfView which does use ETL traces generaeted by the CLR. For GC you would need to programatically enable specific stuff like his. I think the [GCAllocationTick_V1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356162%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#gcallocationtick_v1_event) event would be interesting in your case as well.

If you do keep a reference to your object before you try to get the diff you would get a pretty good understanding how much memory your object graph will consume.

Answer (score 1):

What you can **try** to do is to use exactly the same logic to dump GC state before actually asserting like

```
    // do some logic

    // GC.Collect, Thread.Sleep, ...

    currentCollections[0] = GC.CollectionCount(0);
    currentCollections[1] = GC.CollectionCount(1);
    currentCollections[2] = GC.CollectionCount(2);
```

and after that do asserts with these dumped values (BTW in assertions first parameter is expected, and second one is actual)

```
    for (int generation = 0; generation < generationCollections.Length; generation++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(generationCollections[generation], currentCollections(generation));
    }
```

So this **may** work for most cases, but there is no way to make GC do something - you may just ask it do to something, and then wait in belief...

Comment: I made a mistake. The comment "Test for garbage here" is where code that might potentially generate garbage is. The actual test is the assertion.